# Read cookies with js or jquery which is created by asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cookies, datepicker

I've created a couple of cookies using by ASP.Net C# and I want to read them from client side which of I can use jquery datepicker regional.

```
HttpCookie cookies = new HttpCookie("lang");
        cookies["Language_ID"] = "2";
        cookies["CultureInfo"] = "en";
        cookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookies);
```

This is my asp.net code and result of cookies:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYzYP.png

I want to change language of datepicker paramatically, and this is the jquery code for it. How can I modify it for returning lang>CultureInfo cookies.

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[mycookiecultureinfo]);
```

Comment: There are other and simplest ways to send data from server to the client page, are you sure that you really need to use cookies?

Comment: How can I do that? I am using it different pages, it's a bit complicated.

Comment: And js code is in seperate files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webforms you can put a hiddenfield control on you ASPX page:

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hdfCultureInfo" value="" runat="server"/>
```

And you have to set the value on your code behind:

```
hdfCultureInfo.Value = "en";
```

Now, you can get this value on your script using JQuery:

```
var ci= $('<%=hdfCultureInfo.ClientID%>').val();
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[ci]);
```

---

Another way, if you want to share this data along other pages, you can store on a Session:

```
Session["CultureInfo"] = "us"
```

On the ASPX page, just include this on header before starting your script files:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ci = '<%=(string)Session["CultureInfo"]%>';
</script>
```

---

But if you are using MVC, you can pass values with the ViewData and write anywhere using Razor.